# How to overwrite Instances in Autofac and push it down the object graph?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, instance, autofac

In our mobile app (Xamarin), we register an instance of the current user for use with our Repository (every repository requires an instance of `CurrentUser`).

When we start the app for the first time, we register the Guest User so that we can create our first records before the actual user logs in or registers.

```
    public static UserModel GuestUserForRegistration()
    {
        return new UserModel
        {
            Id = Migration001.GuestUserId,
            Email = Migration001.GuestEmail,
            PasswordHash = Migration001.GuestPassword
        };
    }

    _containerBuilder.RegisterInstance(GuestUserForRegistration());
```

After the app starts up, we have a single entry point where we resolve the MainPage

```
return Container.Resolve<MainPage>();
```

It's at this point that the object graph is built, and we use DI for everything (no service location).

After a user signs in / registers for the first time, we call the following method

```
    public static IContainer Container;

    public static void RegisterCurrentUser(UserModel userModel)
    {
        CurrentUser = userModel;
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterInstance(userModel);
        builder.Update(Container);
    }
```

This method is supposed to do two things.

1. drop the current user into the global static (*working*)
2. register the instance of the user into our IoC Container

The problem is that after the user signs in, if I put a break point in my Repository, the resolved user in the constructor is still guest.

Is this because the object graph has been completely built already using the GuestUser, and therefore the Repository has already been built before I ever updated the Container?

If so, is there a way around this?

Comment: There's some fundamental flaws here. Assuming this is a web app, all users currently accessing the system would be sharing the same instance of UserModel. I'm pretty sure that not what you want. Also, It's not good practice to be updating, or even referencing your container during normal application flow.

Comment: @JimBolla, whoops, did I say it's a web app, if so, that's a mistake. This is a cross platform Android/iOS/WP8 app leveraging Xamarin & Xamarin.Forms with much of the code base shared in a Portable Class Library.

Comment: @JimBolla, also, if it's not good practice to update, then why does the Autofac `ContainerBuilder` have an `Update` method? I'm not referencing the container throughout the app, it fully relies on DI.

Comment: Ok, I assumed web app since that's like 99% of questions. I'll post an answer on how I'd do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 ways you could solve this that don't require your application code to be aware of your container.

The first method, instead replacing the registered instance of `UserModel` with a new instance, you'd just update the registered instances properties to the new values. This is probably the simplest, if your type is mutable and not overly complex.

This second method would be appropriate if updating the original `UserModel` instance is undesirable or impossible. Basically, just add a layer of indirection:

```cs
// -------------------------
// add this class:
public class Changeable<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

// -------------------------
// set up registrations like so:

// register the default value like so
builder.RegisterInstance(
    new Changeable<UserModel>
    {
        Value = new UserModel
            {
                Id = Migration001.GuestUserId,
                Email = Migration001.GuestEmail,
                PasswordHash = Migration001.GuestPassword
            }
     });

// register UserModel directly, which can be used by all the classes that don't
// need to change the instance
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<Changeable<UserModel>>().Value);
```

Now your service classes can take a constructor parameter of either `Changeable<UserModel>` or just `UserModel` depending on whether they need to be able to change the instance or not, with no more direct reference to the container.

Comment: ah, that makes perfect sense. Then in my RegisterCurrentUser method, I pass the UserModel, and simply set the value `Container.Resolve<Changable<UserModel>>().Value = userModel;`

Comment: Yes, but in that case, you're still talking to your container directly, which is something you want to avoid.

Comment: Standard dependency injection. The classes that need to change the UserModel would take a `Changable<UserModel>` as a constructor parameter that gets stored in a field. Then the Register/Login methods can just do `_userModel.Value = newUserModel;`